# How can i prevent a SlideDown and SlideUp (hide/show) events from being triggered by a single mouse click?

Tags: jquery, menu

How can i prevent a SlideDown and SlideUp (hide/show) events from being triggered by a single mouse click?

click on *ANYTHING* but *EVENT* is firing prematurely,

i’m trying to implement a very typical hide/show functionality for a mobile only menu.

the goal is that once the menu slides down and is displayed, if the user clicks anywhere except the menu, it slides back up and gets hidden.

problem is, once it slides down it then slides back up and i’m not sure what is triggering the slideUp function. It seems as if the same mouse click is triggering both,

fyi - i’ve added some stopProgation() code on the menu itself to prohibit slideUp if the menu is clicked on.

fyi - the icon that triggers the slide down in first place gets covered up by the sliding menu but i don’t see how this would be causing the problem. just an fyi

```
jQuery('.mobile-nav-trigger').mousedown( function(){
    jQuery('#mobile-nav').slideDown();
        }
    );

jQuery('.mobile-back-btn').click( function(){ /* back type button so     user can close manually */
    jQuery('#mobile-nav').slideUp();
        }
    );

jQuery('#mobile-nav').bind('click', function(){ /*STOP PROP if Nav is clicked on */
        e.stopPropogation();
    });

jQuery(document).bind('click', function(e){
    if((!jQuery(e.target).is('#mobile-nav')) &&     (!jQuery(e.target).is('.mobile-nav-trigger')))  {
        jQuery('#mobile-nav').slideUp();        
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled Propagation, it should be:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```